# Java requiring a return statement when i'm already providing one

Tags: java

I have made an array class called ListsofUnits which has private fields of a list of Units(object type) and int size.
I am trying to make a function that iterates throught that list and takes an input Unit g and return the first index in which g first comes. If g is not found i am returning -1.

```
     public int indexOf(Unit g) {
         for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++){
             if (g.equals(this.Units[i])) {
                 return i;
                 break;
             } else {
                 return -1;
             }
         }
     }
```

I suspect there might be a syntax error as it keeps asking for a return statement when i already provided one for both cases. Also i would like stop the iteration at the first index where g occurs. I was hoping someone could tell me if this the right way or not. I cannot import any class.

Comment: Your `break` is extraneous. If you return from the loop on any condition on the first iteration, why have a loop?

Comment: Not only extraneous but it should fail to compile. And the method doesn't return if `size < 1`. Also, it never gets past the first iteration. What you want to do is remove the `else` and move the return after the loop.

Comment: What will be returned if `Units` is empty (or `this.size == 0`)?

Comment: @Chris Yeah I get why the break is extraneous but i dont understand what you meant by your second sentence. could you please explain?

Comment: It should return -1 which figured out from the below comment. @Robert

Comment: @Chris Is there any other way to check all the elements in my list?

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails because the `return` statement is used both in the `if` and in the `else`. This would result in exiting in the first iteration, no matter the result. Moreover, the `break` is unnecessary since you use `return` already.

You could try this version as @shmosel also suggested. In this case, you return -1 only after checking all elements without finding a match.

```
public int indexOf(Unit g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
        if (g.equals(this.Units[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Give a person a fish... vs. teach a person to fish. Explain *why* OP's original fails to work like they expected, instead of just giving new code.

Comment: i understand what i was doing wrong. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the loop (`for`). It won't be executed always, for instance, when `this.size=0`. Therefore, you must have a `return` at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains because there is no `return` when you don't enter the loop.

You may say that this can never happen because you initialize `this.size` and `this.Units`, and that may be true, but the compiler doesn't see that; it only looks at that method and that doesn't have a return statement for all possible branches.

If you add `return -1;` in the loop, your program probably doesn't do what you expect. It will check the first array element, and if that's what you're looking for, it returns 0 (the position). So far, so good. If the first element is not what you are looking for, your code enters the `else` branch and returns -1, without even looking at any other element.

To really find an element, you can only `return` after you've either found it or looked at all possible candidates. Remove the `else` branch and move the `return -1;` to after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I am trying to make a function that iterates throught that list and takes an input Unit g and return the first index in which g first comes. If g is not found i am returning -1. ..."*

Return the *−1* value, after the *loop*.

```java
public int indexOf(Unit g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++)
        if (g.equals(this.Units[i])) return i;
    return -1;
}
```

You could even use a *do-while loop* here.

```java
public int indexOf(Unit g) {
    int i = Units.length - 1;
    do if (g.equals(Units[i])) return i;
    while (--i >= 0);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @user85421, it's an _indexOf_ method.

Comment: @user85421, for example, it's not _"firstIndexOf"_ or _"lastIndexOf"_.  You shouldn't expect to know the starting point, if the name only describes returning, the _"indexOf"_.